# Include array from text file in PHP script

Tags: php, arrays, include

I am making a script that outputs a nested array to a text file in PHP. However I am struggling to get other scripts to use the array when I use `include('array.txt');`

I have tried several different methods like `$var = include('array.txt');` or just the include with the var defined inside the text file to no avail.

It is important to note that this file only ever wants to be generated once and the array should not change after that (hence the method of outputting to a text file)

Here is an example of what the array file looks like.

```
array(array('2','30','37','43','104','152','166','193'),array('10','60','95','112','116','163','199','240','242'),array('12','44','80','91','128','138','140','231'),array('19','38','102','111','130','134','175','207','210','246'))
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: save it as json_encode and the decode it back?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change the file extension to .php for the output file. A .php is just a text file with the .php extension. Then you can use the include function to include the php file.

Answer (score 0):

Use serialization:

```
file_put_contents ($filename, serialize ($array)); // write to file
$array = unserialize (file_get_contents ($filename)); // retrieve
```

---

Or JSON encoding:

```
file_put_contents ($filename, json_encode ($array)); // write to file
$array = json_decode (file_get_contents ($filename), true); // retrieve
```

---

Also, it might be a good idea to use gzip encoding to save disk space. (using [gzencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) and [gzdecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php))

Comment: Thanks but for some reason that wouldn't work but Azoloths method works perfectly.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? Azoloth's method is actually a pretty bad idea because it takes up way more space and isn't the way it should be done - serialization and JSON encoding were made for this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but I didn't spend to much time figuring it out. And I cant see how it will take up any less space really as far as i could tell they just put them in speech marks and added json infront of it. And the file is only going to be at the extreme top end 10kb big. but normally 2kb